# Same height in row?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I use the same height in row that keeps the site responsive? For example I have two x_panel with rows and columns inside but the height is different, i tried use display flex, but it change inside columns...

Here is a code to you understand what I'm trying to do:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="x_panel tile">
   <div class="x_content">
    <div class="row x_title">
     <h3>Ponto de Venda:<small id="node_name"></small></h3>       
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"> 
      <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
       <h5>Período de Avaliação:</h5> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
       <div id="reportrange" class="pull-right" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; width: 100%; text-align: center; border: 1px solid #ccc">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>
        <span id="grafico_medias"></span> <b class="caret"></b>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row tile_count text-center">
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 tile_stats_count">
      <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Total de Pedestres</span>
       <div id="displayPedestres" class="count"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 tile_stats_count">
      <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Visualizações</span>
      <div id="displayInteracoes" class="count"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 tile_stats_count">
      <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Taxa de Conversão</span>
      <div id="displayTaxa" class="count green"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!-- /Informacoes medias -->
  
 <!-- Meta -->
 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="x_panel tile">
   <div class="x_content">
    <div class="row x_title">
     <h3>Meta</h3>       
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="row">  
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">           
       <h5>Meta do</h5>
      </div>         
      <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="text-align: right">
       <select id="metaPeriodo" onchange="meta()" class="pull-right" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; width: 100%; text-align: center; border: 1px solid #ccc">
        <option>dia</option>
        <option>mês</option>
        <option>trimestre</option>
       </select>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"> 
       <h5>em</h5>
      </div> 
      <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="text-align: right">
       <select  id="metaVariavel" class="pull-right" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; width: 100%; text-align: center; border: 1px solid #ccc" id="tipo_meta" onclick="meta()">
        <option>pedestres</option>
        <option>visualizações</option>
        <option>taxa de conversão</option>
       </select>
      </div>
     </div>
     <br>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <input id="metaInput" type="text" class="form-control has-feedback" placeholder="Insira aqui a meta" style="height: 68px; font-size: 40px; font-weight: 600; color: #73879C; text-align: center">
                        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="sidebar-widget text-center">
       <h4 style="text-align: center;">Cumprimento da Meta</h4>
       <canvas width="140" height="80" id="foo" class="" style="width: 150px; height: 100px;"></canvas>
       <div class="goal-wrapper" style="text-align: center;">
        <span class="gauge-value pull-center"></span>
        <span id="gauge-text" class="gauge-value pull-center"></span>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>     
 <!-- /Meta -->
</div>
```

I would like to "sync" this two columns  with the same height doesn't matter the size of screen, can you help me?

**EDIT**

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5nzcpj3s/

I am using Bootstrap with gentelella layout

Comment: can you set up a fiddle?

Comment: can you clarify with your CSS ? i linked your HTML to bootstrap library, is that right ?

Comment: sorry, i added an edit to you see the code

Comment: quick test : https://jsfiddle.net/8jz4h5az/3/ with flex. css update at the bottom (resize width to see behavior)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/frd28kk0

I added new CSS classes just to make it easier to understand.

You have to play with the margins to get it better.

Your flexbox idea was fine. I guess you only missed setting `.so-col-1` as `display: flex;` as well.

Boa sorte! =]

Comment: I added display: flex; to so-col-2 and now is working perfectly with same size! Thank you so much to help my noob question hahaha

Answer (score 0):

with [flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and adding a single css class:

`<div class="row flexit">...</div>`

```
.flexit {
  display:flex;
}
.flexit > div {
  flex:1; 
}
```

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/egBemm)